# ng model not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the value using ng-model (passing values via function).

My codes look like

Input tag:

```
   <input name="comments" ng-model="comments" class="form-control" type="text">
```

Grid Table :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
   <td><input type="radio" ng-click="callvalues(value.CUSTID);"></td>
```

Angularjs code:

```
$scope.callvalues = function($scope,custID){
     alert("custID");
};
```

I am getting custID is not defined. I try to hardcore values

```
 $scope.callvalues = function($scope,custID){
      $scope.comments = "122";
};
```

NO error in console but it's also not working.

Comment: Just remove the first parameter `$scope` from your functions. You need to add that only to controllers.

Comment: Do you have value object on your controller scope?

Comment: if removed $scope,i am getting values.How to set value using ng-model

Comment: your function is expecting *two* parameters on the function call (`$scope` and `custID`) but is only receiving one (`value.CUSTID`).  This value is going to be written to the first parameter in the function (`$scope`), the second will be `null`, and the `$scope` local to this function will hide the `$scope` service.

Comment: also, it's not really clear what the relationship between these radio buttons in the `ng-repeat` and the input that has the `ng-model` is.  the `ng-repeat` implies that there are multiple groups of radio button options, but you seem to only be trying to set a single input box.

Comment: Assign that value to your model like $scope."model name here"="your value";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is click in radio button and alert value you can try this code

```
$scope.callvalues = function(custID){
     alert(custID);
    $scope.comments = custID;
};
```

plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/CYi3e2D0xLkWksr9p4y8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

remove $scope parameter from your function 
from
$scope.callvalues = function($scope,custID){
 to 
$scope.callvalues = function(custID){

Answer (score 0):

Grid Table

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in values">
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="selectedRadio" ng-value="value.CUSTID" ng-click="callvalues(selectedRadio);"></td>
```

Controller

```
$scope.callvalues = function(custID){
 //console.log($scope.selectedRadio); 
 alert(custID);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass $scope as method argument. You can read it's values in any method inide of Controller.

```
$scope.callvalues = function(custID){
     alert("custID");
     $scope.comments = custID;
};
```